# Conditional Form Validation Alternate Option

Tags: codeigniter, validation

i have the following html in a form

```
<input type="radio" name="has_item" id="item_yes" value="1" checked
                                    onchange="toggle_variant(this.value)">
                                    Yes

<input type="radio" name="has_item" id="item_no" value="0" 
                                    onchange="toggle_variant(this.value)">
                                    No


<input type="text" name="price" id="price" />
```

Now i want to check that if value of has_item = 0,
then form_validate whether price is required|numeric

so i write this condition

```
$has_item = $this->input->post('has_item');

if($has_item == 1)
   {
     $this->form_validation->set_rules('price', 'Product Price', 'required|numeric');
   }
```

is it right, or there is some better way of doing so?

Also how can I validate whether `$this->input->post('has_item') != '0.00';`

Comment: `has_item !=0.00` or `price!=0.00` a typo ?

Comment: typo means? I am new to this word.

Comment: `greater_than` in the form validation or create a custom call back function.

Answer (score 1):

there is a better approach for this

```
   $price_required=''
   if($this->input->post('has_item')==1) $price_required='|required';
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('price', 'Product Price', 'numeric'.$price_required);
```